# raise Value_Error doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, exception, raise

```
try:
    if(a>b):
       raise Value_Error;
    else:
       print("no err");
except "Value_Error":
    print("value error ...");
else:
    print("a is smaller");
```

value error is not getting printed or the raise statement is not raising the exception. Could someone help me by making "value error..." getting printed

Comment: What's up with the underscore and the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Corrected:

```
try:
    if a > b:
       raise ValueError()
    else:
       print("no err")
except ValueError:
    print("value error ...")
else:
    print("a is smaller")
```